# Unable to get MIN and MAX time from a Datetime Column from every backday

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get `MIN` and `MAX` time from a `Datetime` (`InOut`) column but output is same for both column.

My query:

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12),MIN(Punch_history.Ecode)) as EmpCode,
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12),MIN(EmployeeMaster.RecommandedBy)) as EmpID,
  convert(date, InOut) as Report_date,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(InOut),108) as InTime,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(InOut),108) as OutTime,
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12),MIN(TID)) as LOCATION
  FROM Punch_history inner join EmployeeMaster on Punch_history.ECode = EmployeeMaster.Ecode
  where CAST (InOut as DATE) between  CAST(getdate() -1 as DATE ) and CAST(getdate() -1 as DATE ) and 
  EmployeeMaster.RecommandedBy like 'M0%' group by EmpID,InOut
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We need a bit more detail to be able to help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: It is because you are grouping by InOut, this is the same thing you are trying to get Min Max of...

Comment: Sample input???  Expected output???

Comment: it showing error when i giving other clause to group by, Expected output should be two different time for a day

Comment: join another table to data like below query  SELECT
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12),MIN(Punch_history.Ecode)) as EmpCode,
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12),MIN(EmployeeMaster.RecommandedBy)) as EmpID,
  convert(date, InOut) as Report_date,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(InOut),108) as InTime,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(InOut),108) as OutTime
  FROM Punch_history inner join EmployeeMaster on Punch_history.ECode = EmployeeMaster.Ecode
  where CAST (InOut as DATE) between  CAST(getdate() -1 as DATE ) and CAST(getdate() -1 as DATE ) 
  and EmployeeMaster.RecommandedBy like 'M0%' group by convert(date, InOut)

Comment: You really can't put queries in the comments. The formatting makes them useless. And now you are adding new tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try grouping by the converted date instead of inout.

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12),MIN(Punch_history.Ecode)) as EmpCode,
  convert(date, InOut) as Report_date,
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),min(InOut),108) as InTime,
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),max(InOut),108) as OutTime
  FROM Punch_history 
  where CAST (InOut as DATE) between  CAST(getdate() -1 as DATE ) 
    and CAST(getdate() -1 as DATE ) 
  group by EmpID, convert(date, InOut)
```

Comment: sorry its getting error like... Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Column 'Punch_history.InOut' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: its worked but getting error if i need to add two more could from another table..

Comment: query --  SELECT
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12),MIN(Punch_history.Ecode)) as EmpCode,
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12),MIN(EmployeeMaster.RecommandedBy)) as EmpID,
  convert(date, InOut) as Report_date,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(InOut),108) as InTime,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(InOut),108) as OutTime
  FROM Punch_history inner join EmployeeMaster on Punch_history.ECode = EmployeeMaster.Ecode
  where CAST (InOut as DATE) between  CAST(getdate() -1 as DATE ) and CAST(getdate() -1 as DATE ) 
  and EmployeeMaster.RecommandedBy like 'M0%' group by convert(date, InOut)

Comment: I think it would be easier if you showed your tables in the question

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the grouping issue your where clause is quite strange. First of all using shortcuts for date math is a no win situation. It will fail with datetime2. And using between two identical values is just strange.

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), MIN(Punch_history.Ecode)) as EmpCode,
    convert(date, MIN(InOut)) as Report_date,
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), min(InOut), 108) as InTime,
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), max(InOut), 108) as OutTime
FROM Punch_history 
where convert(date, InOut) = convert(date, dateadd(day, -1, getdate()))
group by EmpID
```

Comment: Getting error - Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The *major issue* is that you should not group by InOut (datetime), that is why in the result max and min are the same. Actually, this is cancelling the grouping which you want to happen on daily basis.

```
  SELECT
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12),MIN(Punch_history.Empcode)) as EmpCode,
  CONVERT(DATE , Max(InOut)) as Report_date,
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),min(InOut),108) as InTime,
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),max(InOut),108) as OutTime
  FROM Punch_history 
  where datediff(day, CAST(InOut as DATE ) , CAST(getdate() as DATE ) )=1
  group  by EmpID
```

In addition, if empid and empcode are 1-1 (logically they should be)
   then you      can group directly with empcode, or both of them
   avoiding this rather strange    Min(empcode).